# На википедии про Xdebug сказано «Поддерживается также выполнение произвольного кода на точке останова...». А как это сделать?

Tags: php, xdebug

Как мне во время отладки сайта, когда его работа остановилась в точке останова, выполнить произвольный php код? 
Желательно напишите про PhpStorm (я пишу в этой IDE).

Comment: ну насколько я знаю, это нельзя сделать, точка останова для того и придумана, чтобы остановить выполнение и посмотреть процесс

Comment: Видимо ошибка в вики))) В англ. версии такого нет. Видимо имелось в виду, что можно задавать условные точки останова при соблюдении неких условий

Comment: Для этого в большинстве IDE есть evaluate или watches, в которые можно выполнить произвольный код. (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/evaluating-expressions.html, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debug-tool-window-watches.html)